# Multilevel relationship whereHas

Tags: laravel

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way... I'm not much of an expert on this, but I need the following:

Get all the timelines that in the user profile the privacy_community is 1.

**MODEL USER**

```
public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }



Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->text('biography')->nullable();
            $table->string('url')->nullable();
            $table->string('img_thumb')->nullable();
            $table->string('img_medium')->nullable();
            $table->string('img_large')->nullable();
            $table->enum('privacity_profile', [Profile::PUBLICO, Profile::PRIVADO])->default(Profile::PUBLICO);
            $table->enum('privacity_comunity', [Profile::PUBLICO, Profile::PRIVADO])->default(Profile::PUBLICO);
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }





Schema::create('timelines', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

**Model Timeline**

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

I'm trying to do it this way but it doesn't work:

```
$contents = Timeline::whereHas('user', function($query){
                 $query->whereHas('profile', function ($query) {
                     $query->where('privacity_comunity', 1);
                 });
             })
            ->get();
```

I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Query/approach looks fine can you please elaborate what doesn't work ? are you getting invalid data or any error, would be good if you can include sample data/output and highlight the wrong part

Comment: It doesn't give any error but the result is empty and the table has records so it should show it.

Comment: Thanks, it's fixed! it was a cache error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$contents = Timeline::whereHas('user', function($query){
                 $query->whereHas('profile', function ($query) {
                     $query->where('privacity_comunity', 1);
                 });
             })
            ->get();
```

**Timeline** model must have function **user** and **user** must have **profile** function.

you may try that way, Hope that will be helpful.

Comment: What is the difference between the OP's approach and yours? there is a user and profile relation in their respective models. Please read the question clearly before posting your answer

Comment: It is exactly the same as what has already been done